# R Plotly: Why does my whole plot disappear when I try to add annotations in a list?

Tags: r, plot, layout, annotations, plotly

I've made a function that outputs a graph. I can add an annotation to it just fine, but if I try to add *two* annotations in a list (which is what the documentation tells me to do), the whole plot disappears.

Here is code that works:

```
a <-  list(
    x = 0,
    y = 1.05,
    text = 'Quotes',
    xref = "paper",
    yref = "paper",
    showarrow = F
  )
  
  b <-  list(
    x = 1,
    y = 1.05,
    text = 'Sales',
    xref = "paper",
    yref = "paper",
    showarrow = F
  )

function1(dt) %>% 
  layout(annotations = a)

function1(dt) %>% 
  layout(annotations = b)
```

But if I run the below line, the whole plot goes blank (no axes or anything):

```
function1(dt) %>% 
  layout(annotations = list(a,b))
```

Has anyone come across this problem before? Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind providing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code of your function `function1` and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: ... this said: Your code works fine when I test on a simple scatterplot `function1 <- function(dt) plot_ly(dt, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")` and making use of some simple fake data `dt <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, length.out = 10), y = seq(0, 1, length.out = 10))`.

Comment: Ah, I used the dataset you just made and I still get a blank plot. Do you think it's maybe just some glitch with my version of R? My friend ran my code and experienced the same problem.

Comment: Hm. Always my first option: Restart R. Run the code again. (: Second I would check `packageVersion("plotly")`. Mine is `4.10.0`.

Comment: Ah. My plotly is only 4.5.2! It seems to be the most up-to-date I can get with my work's version of RStudio (1.0.136). Huh oh well maybe I can find some really offensive work-around for my double annotation. Thank you for your help though